# Как обернуть два тега в общий по критериям id и атрибуту?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как обернуть два элемента в общий div с классом `.similar` по критериям совпадения id и атрибута двух элементов?

```html
<input for="name1" type="radio">
<label id="name1">Первый блок</div>
<br>
<input for="name2" type="radio">
<label id="name2">Второй блок</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рискну предположить, что Вам надо только для `input` типа `radio`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[type="radio"]').each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $('#' + id + ', [for="' + id + '"]').wrapAll("<div class='similar'/>");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="name1" type="radio">
<label for="name1">Первый блок</label>
<br>
<input id="name2" type="radio">
<label for="name2">Второй блок</label>
```